# bootstrap background size cover not full

Tags: css

I want to ask

I have a script for full screen, position fixed, but not full

This the screenshoot :

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XiCq.jpg)

My code:

```css
    .affix{bottom:-1px; width: 100%; display:block; background-size: cover !important; position:fixed !important; z-index: 9999 !important;}
```

```html
    <div class="affix" style="background-color:#43A047; margin-top:-1px;">
    <a href="http://myweb.com" target="_blank"><center><h3 style="color:#ffffff; padding:8px; margin:0px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> CLICKED...</h3></center></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: We need to see the rest of your HTML and CSS in order to help you

Comment: try `width: 100vw; left:0px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try set `left:0` and `width:100vw;`** 
Here is JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/a1b5qoj0/5/ 
**Learn about `vw`:**https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

```css
.affix{
bottom:-1px; 
width:100vw; 
display:block; 
background-size: 
cover !important; 
position:fixed !important; 
z-index: 9999 !important;
left:0
}
```

```html
<div class="affix" style="background-color:#43A047; margin-top:-1px;">
<a href="http://myweb.com" target="_blank">
<center>
<h3 style="color:#ffffff; padding:8px; margin:0px;">
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">
</i> CLICKED...
</h3>
</center>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: thanks for reply sir, i forget to set left:0; thank again sir for help

Answer (score 0):

You need reset CSS:

```
* { padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
```